Hot dust contribution to whirlwinds forming
My father observed an event with a whirlwind and had an aha moment on its forming. What he saw was a weak wind blowing over a sun heated patch of dust, and when the dust rose up, all of suddenly a strong whirlwind appeared taking some nearby papers really high in the sky, couple of hundred meters maybe. His explanation is that when the heated dust rose, it vastly increased the surface area and released the stored heat quickly, which induced the whirlwind. The whirlwind possibly raised more dust which released more energy and so on.
While this explanation does have intuitive merits, I am a bit skeptical. It is hard to see if the stored energy in the dust is of the same magnitude of the energy in the whirlwind. I was not able to find any source on whirlwind formation that mentions dust in any other way than giving it visibility. There can be other explanations we are unaware of and might be better fitting. Intuition is useful to guide you towards an explanation, but not sufficient to conclude one.
So could anyone here tell if this explanation is any good? Is there something in the explanation that is wrong? How much role does the dust play in the whirlwind formation? The answer here gives a nice quote from Wikipedia, but there is no dust mentioned.

If it was a dust devil your father saw, then the explanation is given in the linked answer (i.e., formed by air & made visible by dust/dirt/debris).

The quote is not saying anything about the dust's contribution to the formation. However, now that I actually went to the Wikipedia page from where the quote is, there is an additional sentence that says that dust is not necessary for the formation. Still, it might be possible that when the dust is present it "amplifies" the dust devil. I guess I would like a confirmation or refutation that dust can not store enough energy to significantly contribute.
